# How to do cyclic order by value in an array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a timezone offset array and a current time zone offset.

```
    $offsets = array(-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9);
    $currentOff = -6; //user's timezone always change zone to zone
```

Here is what I need

```
    $result = array(-6,-7,-8,-9,-4,-5); 
    //ordering should start with the $currentOff.
```

I've gone through some array references in php but can't make it. Excited to here from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the index, slice the array, merge the slices:

```
$index = array_search($currentOff, $offsets);
$result = array_merge(array_slice($offsets, $index), array_slice($offsets, 0, $index));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and it's worked like charm.But so silly SO team not allowing me to tick your answer.